# Jquery ui Dialog in an MVC listing table

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a listing table displaying some information from the database.

What i am trying to do is to check if the item status is 1 and if comments exists to display a little icon where the user will click on it and see the specific comment for that item.

So in the listing table it seems to display fine that icon according to the above criteria but when i click on a specific listing it opens all dialogs with comments for all other listings with the same item status instead of the one i have chosen.

Can you please help me on what am i doing wrong ?

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BookingId)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="@Url.Action("ItemDetails", new {id=item.ItemId })" title="@item.Item.ItemDescription">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Item.ItemName)
                </a>
        </td>
          <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndDate)
        </td>
         <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RequestDate)
        </td>
        @if (item.StatusCodeId == 1)
        {
         <td style="color:#DD7500">

            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StatusCode.StatusCodeName)

             @if (item.Comments != null)
             {                                 
              <img class="orangeclicker" style="margin-left:3px;display:inline;margin-bottom:-3px;cursor: pointer;" title="Tutor Comments" src="~/Images/chat_icon.gif" /> 

                      <div class="orangedialog" title="Tutor Comments"> 
                     <p> @item.Comments</p>
                     </div>                          
             }            
        </td>
        }
                }                      
    </tr>   
}   
</table>  
<script>  $(function ()
  {    
      $(" .orangedialog").dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          show: { effect: "blind", duration: 1000 },
          hide: { effect: "explode", duration: 1000 },
          buttons: {
              Close: function () {
                  $(this).dialog("close");
              }
          }
      });

      $('.orangeclicker').live("click", function () {
         $(".orangedialog").dialog("open");        

      });         
  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

They all have the same `id` or `class` ( because they are render in a `foreach` statement )

You can add a difference by combining the class or the id with the `index` from your `list`

I don't have the code in front of me, but I also think something like this would work.

UPDATE:

```
 $('.orangeclicker').live("click", function (e) {
     alert("check"); // if this fires at click, the problem is somewhere else
     var target= $(e.currentTarget);
     target.next().dialog("open");        

  });
```

Comment: Have you removed the space from the beginning of your script ?       here : $(" .orangedialog").dialog({ . Also, if the check fires and it fires only once, the code I've gave you it's good. The problem is when you initialize the dialog I think

Comment: Yes , i have removed the space and the dialog fires only ones. Also i have checked the html and it renders fine the comments...

Comment: no , i mean it renders fine the comments as it did before just in html but the dialog is not firing at all (if i remove the check)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

first;you have to create links in each row of table having same class.

```
<a class="comments">Comments</a>
```

second; update your page as:

```
<div id="dialog-details" style="display: none">
  <p>
   @if (item.Comments != null)
         {                                 
          <img class="orangeclicker" style="margin-left:3px;display:inline;margin-bottom:-3px;cursor: pointer;" title="Tutor Comments" src="~/Images/chat_icon.gif" /> 

                  <div class="orangedialog" title="Tutor Comments"> 
                 <p> @item.Comments</p>
                 </div>                          
         }   
   </p>
 </div>
```

third update your script as:

```
    $('.comments').click(function () {
       $("#dialog-details").dialog('open');
     return false;
});
  $("#dialog-details").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    height: 170,
    width: 350,
    show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
    modal: true,
    draggable: true,
    open: function (event, ui) {
        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();

    },
    buttons: {

        "Close": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: i am not sure where do you mean to create the links ?

Comment: first you need to have links to be created in your table's row so that the onclick event get called and open the dialog.

Comment: you need this @if (item.StatusCodeId == 1)
        { <a class="comments">Comments</a>   } so that if Status code is 1 than the links get appears and onClick the dialog will open.

Comment: nop , i tried that as well and its not firing at all :(

Answer (score 0):

You should Use `$(this).next().next().find(".orangedialog")` to find relevent element.

```
$('.orangeclicker').on("click", function (e) {
    $element = $(this).next().next().find(".orangedialog");
    $element.dialog("open"); 
});
```

Update

**Use `on()` instead of `live()`**

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PL9X9/)

Comment: No nothing , still it doesnt fire the dialog although i checked the html and it seems that it renders all the comments in html

Comment: Does click event fire at all? Did you see the demo, is that the way your comments renders?

Comment: all the comments render just in html as before but the dialog is not firing at all...

Comment: event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: could you possibly help me with teamviewer?